# Pointgrey Camera Driver Kinetic Ubuntu package unauthenticated

Tags: ros, rosdep, ros-kinetic, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running the ROS Kinetic docker container and using `rosdep` to install the Pointgrey Camera Driver package, but I'm getting this error:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  ros-kinetic-pointgrey-camera-driver
E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-kinetic-pointgrey-camera-driver] failed
```

I'm not a fan of `--allow-unauthenticated`.  Is this expected behavior?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338343/pointgrey-camera-driver-kinetic-ubuntu-package-unauthenticated/) by [dustingooding](https://answers.ros.org/users/3314/dustingooding/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2019-11-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-22**:\

> I'm running the ROS Kinetic docker container [..]

how old is that image?

This could be #q325039 if the image is old enough.

A `docker pull ros:kinetic` would show whether there is a newer image.

Finally: it's not necessarily about that specific package. The error typically indicates there was *some* problem verifying files from that repository and you just happen to try and install that one.

**Comment by [dustingooding](https://answers.ros.org/users/3314/dustingooding/) on 2019-11-24**:
I tried it on a fresh image.

```
dgooding@createbonfire:~$ docker pull ros:kinetic
kinetic: Pulling from library/ros
Digest: sha256:9186eb099225cf76e072c9918ead9f428409de48162ebc4f9f6136ebe44cfe3f
Status: Image is up to date for ros:kinetic
docker.io/library/ros:kinetic
dgooding@createbonfire:~$ docker run -it ros:kinetic /bin/bash
root@08ed36a689db:/# apt-get update -qqy
root@08ed36a689db:/# apt-get install ros-kinetic-pointgrey-camera-driver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-pointgrey-camera-driver
```

When I do this from a super fresh official image, the driver package isn't even there.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-25**:
Not sure why at this point, but it looks like that package is actually not available for Kinetic: [status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=pointgrey](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=pointgrey). Notice the red squares in the `X64` and `X32` columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This doesn't appear to be a problem with keys or with unauthenticated packages, as the package just really isn't there.

The Pointgrey camera driver builds are broken:

- [ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver#188](https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver/issues/188)
- [ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver#113](https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver/issues/113)

Some users have been able to retrieve the `.deb` from the snapshot repository ([ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver#188#issuecomment-521527548](https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver/issues/188#issuecomment-521527548)). As it probably hasn't changed much over the years, that could be a short-term workaround.

It would perhaps be nice to help @mikepurvis fix the underlying problem.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1